# How long will it take for a dual core computer to sort a billion files by a specific characteristic?

Tags: performance, file

I just wanted to ask assuming there is a dual core computer with 3 gigabytes of RAM, how long will it take for this computer to sort a billion files by a special and specific charachteristic such as "size", "date moified", "name" or etc? And generally what are the fundamentals and basis of such calculation? Suppose we have a quad core computer with 8 gigabytes of RAM, how could we calculate that how long it will take for such computer to sort 495 thousand files by a special charachteristic such as name?

I want to develop a software that could predict the chance of success of a game according to it's past history. Like the average goals per match, goals for and against and etc. I want to accumulate about 50 thousand games and their results and finally calculate the chance of success in ech of them according some parameters like the totall goals for and against average goals per match. like the software calculates what percentage of matches that both teams have at least 1.4 goals for in every match will end in over 2.5?

Comment: This is throttled by disk I/O throughput.  Nothing sane can be said about it without thorough specifications of the disk sub-system and the size of the files.

Answer (score 0):

O(NLOGN)  basis? because basically if you can get a pointer to all the files wich i think might be possile( too lazy to calculate) then your best algorithm would be quicksort wich is NlogN , if you dont have enough space you would use something like a N-way sorting method wich is also NLogN well most precisely 2NLog(B-1)N  (B-1 is the base of log and N is the number of pointer in memory.

Comment: forgot to mention plus the time of the OS responding to querying for the values.